# how to encrypt and decrypt a String(Plain Text) with RSA public key in ios, swift

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, rsa

I want to `Encrypt` a string(Plain Text) with my `RSA` public key. I have a `public key`, which sent from the server as a `String` and with that I created a `RSA` public key. now I want to use that key to `Encrypt` my text with padding `PKACS12`. how can I do that. I went through lots of stack overflow questions and I didn't get any success.

this is how I create the `RSA public key`,

```
let serverPublicKey = "Some text with key"

let data2 = Data.init(base64Encoded: serverPublicKey)

let keyDict:[NSObject:NSObject] = [
  kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
  kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
  kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: NSNumber(value: 2048),
  kSecReturnPersistentRef: true as NSObject
 ]

let publickeysi = SecKeyCreateWithData(data2! as CFData, keyDict as CFDictionary, nil)
```

this creates a `RSA public key` successfully. now I want to use this key to encrypt my another `Plain Text`. how can I do that.

Comment: Wait.. you receive a public key from a server, and with that key you want to create another public key? Are you sure about that?

Comment: its actually not a key, its a `String` with `server public key`. with that I create a `RSA public key`

Comment: Ok, so your question is basically "How to use RSA encryption with swift", correct?

Comment: @DavidG yep. correct

Comment: I see. What have you tried so far? Did you look into tutorials and run some example code? If yes, where exactly are you stuck? Update your post with the code in question, highlight the problematic part and add a brief description of what you tried to fix it.

Comment: If you are happy to use open source code, take a look at SwiftyRSA.

Comment: per @Paulw11: [SwiftyRSA](https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA). Looks good, good documentation and comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hope this will help you:

```
let serverPublicKey = "Some text with key"

    let data2 = Data.init(base64Encoded: serverPublicKey)

    let keyDict:[NSObject:NSObject] = [
      kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
      kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
      kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: NSNumber(value: 2048),
      kSecReturnPersistentRef: true as NSObject
     ]

    let publickeysi = SecKeyCreateWithData(data2! as CFData, keyDict as CFDictionary, nil)

    //Encrypt a string with the public key
            let message = "This is my message."
            let blockSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publickeysi!)
            var messageEncrypted = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: blockSize)
            var messageEncryptedSize = blockSize

            var status: OSStatus!

            status = SecKeyEncrypt(publickeysi!, SecPadding.PKCS1, message, message.characters.count, &messageEncrypted, &messageEncryptedSize)

            if status != noErr {
                print("Encryption Error!")
                return
            }
```

Comment: Thanks and this http://studyswift.blogspot.com/2016/01/encrypt-decrypt-string-with-code.html will help more if anyone need this.

Comment: @AnuradhS how do I get base64String of the encrypted data?

Comment: How can we get  base64String of encrypted data ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 9):

```
import Foundation
import Security


struct RSA {

static func encrypt(string: String, publicKey: String?) -> String? {
    guard let publicKey = publicKey else { return nil }

    let keyString = publicKey.replacingOccurrences(of: "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----", with: "")
    guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: keyString) else { return nil }

    var attributes: CFDictionary {
        return [kSecAttrKeyType         : kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
                kSecAttrKeyClass        : kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
                kSecAttrKeySizeInBits   : 2048,
                kSecReturnPersistentRef : true] as CFDictionary
    }

    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil
    guard let secKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(data as CFData, attributes, &error) else {
        print(error.debugDescription)
        return nil
    }
    return encrypt(string: string, publicKey: secKey)
}

static func encrypt(string: String, publicKey: SecKey) -> String? {
    let buffer = [UInt8](string.utf8)

    var keySize   = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey)
    var keyBuffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: keySize)

    // Encrypto  should less than key length
    guard SecKeyEncrypt(publicKey, SecPadding.PKCS1, buffer, buffer.count, &keyBuffer, &keySize) == errSecSuccess else { return nil }
    return Data(bytes: keyBuffer, count: keySize).base64EncodedString()
   }
}
```

Use like this

```
var pemString = "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAl/zjMK4w1XZAnpIqLeTAMW7cEUNIifP3HjmUavvc2+oPG1QjNCfxQM6LulZSl6qRim2JGxbc3yvnbMRJqch6IhJ/ysbTekVSqOjskIRGxq0pg0J8PqF3ZZQK6D7BYHi6iaJUMVV0ISB5LogJouyOWqsZyiEjgPz3jj0HIrh14Q6wPZVMpVbIwQR9nZp5gU5minseCyZfQs3PArgXgnzRPdw7Hb0/NY5OVE2Rz1SFTnda6w12SEu1IsVhVhJz1QteNrwNwJAT6WgZd+xnOZhU3Ei+EQK2SijfEGqmWNt1utJygK/0APy8w7VTol7ygbqfuHevGcg90QEXjxZKCjkXkQIDAQAB\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----"


let password = "abcdefg"
let encryptedPassword = RSA.encrypt(string: password, publicKey: pemString)
print(encryptedPassword)
```

Comment: getting nil as a result using method Data(base64Encoded: keyString), I am passing proper keyString value having no -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n, etc. What to do here to get Data?

Comment: Removed /r and /n received in public key in between then used Data(base64Encoded: keyString) and it's worked.

Comment: reference for objective C?

Comment: I am getting errSecParam status, I am not sure which parameter is wrong, can you help @Den

Comment: @Dinesh_Kachhot Can you upload the pem string you tested?