# Encrypt data with external key in swift

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, rsa

I'm supposed to encrypt some data with a string public key sent from a server through HTTPS and send back to the server.

I did a lot of research and also studied these topics plus a lot of other things related to it but couldn't solve my problem.

All I'm saying is that I cannot convert a string to a seckey to use this function.

```
func SecKeyEncrypt(_ key: SecKey, 
             _ padding: SecPadding, 
             _ plainText: UnsafePointer<UInt8>, 
             _ plainTextLen: Int, 
             _ cipherText: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, 
             _ cipherTextLen: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>) -> OSStatus
```

1-[how to encrypt and decrypt a String(Plain Text) with RSA public key in ios, swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45837134/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-stringplain-text-with-rsa-public-key-in-ios-swif)

2-https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/using_keys_for_encryption

This is MyCode for encryption:

```
let publickey : SecKey = "# -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----  some key  ---- 
END PUBLIC KEY----- #" as! SecKey

let message = "plain text"
let blockSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey!)
var messageEncrypted = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: blockSize)
var messageEncryptedSize = blockSize

var status: OSStatus!
        status = SecKeyEncrypt(publickey!, SecPadding(rawValue: 0), message, 
message.characters.count, &messageEncrypted, &messageEncryptedSize)
```

app get crashed at the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You can't say

```
let publickey : SecKey = 
    "# -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----  some key  ----END PUBLIC KEY----- #" as! SecKey
```

You cannot just take a String and somehow magically cast it as a SecKey. You have to *derive* the SecKey from the public key.

Comment: See the link you yourself cited, as well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808101/seckey-from-public-key-string-from-server-in-swift and others.

Comment: I know it doesn't work but i didn't know what to do,please tell me a little about "derive the seckey from the public key" I started ios programming recently and trying hard to learn some of the concepts..forgive me

Comment: You’ve two links with code already. I’m just explaining the crash! :) It’s odd that Swift doesn’t warn that the cast can’t work but that’s another story.

Comment: CoreFoundation types all are, deep-down, `void*`, so they always succeed `as!` casting. `let x = "" as! CFArray` works, too. You should only ever use `as` casting (never `as!` casting) on CFTypes unless you really really really know what you're doing.

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks, I knew it was something like that, but I feel Swift should be smarter about this. It supposedly knows what CFRef types are toll-free bridged to which object types and which are not.

Answer (score 0):

You're 90% there with that first link. The important piece is this:

```
let data2 = Data.init(base64Encoded: serverPublicKey)
```

It expects the input to be Base64 encoded, which your data is, except you also have a that `# -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` prefix (and the suffix). You need to pull those off before trying to base64-decode the data. Make sure that `data2` has legitimate data in it.

Try using `String.dropFirst(Int)` and `String.dropLast(Int)`, and you should be able to trim your input into something that is just Base64. (You may also need to run it through `filter { $0 != "\n" }`.)

That should get you where you need to go. Let me know if you're still stuck; I've got code lying around somewhere that does it, but I don't have it on hand.