# RSA key creation always nil

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, rsa

So I have a requirement where i have to encrypt `Strings` using ***RSA***.

Have a look on this clipboard[image: Example]

So after doing some researching i have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45839803/8192960) could be the right answer for my case.

After modifying the code to form this at the last stage.

```
 private func encrypt(with key: String) {
    let serverPublicKey = key.data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedData()
    guard let serverPublicKey2 = serverPublicKey else { return }
    let data2 = Data(base64Encoded: serverPublicKey2)
    guard  let data = data2 else { return }
    let keyDict:[NSObject:NSObject] = [
        kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
        kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: NSNumber(value: 2048),
        kSecReturnPersistentRef: true as NSObject
    ]
    let publickeysi = SecKeyCreateWithData(data as CFData, keyDict as CFDictionary, nil)
    guard let publicKeySi = publickeysi else { return }
    //Encrypt a string with the public key
    let message = "This is my message." // this field in bullet point one 
    let blockSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKeySi)
    var messageEncrypted = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: blockSize)
    var messageEncryptedSize = blockSize
    var status: OSStatus!
    status = SecKeyEncrypt(publickeysi!, SecPadding.PKCS1, message, message.count, &messageEncrypted, &messageEncryptedSize)
    if status != noErr {
        print("Encryption Error!")
        return
    }
}
```

- I Don't know what is `message` field stands for, and based on my requirement is this where i need to put my `UUID` / `Pin` & server `PublicKey`.
- function escapes the closure at `SecKeyCreateWithData` as it's always returning `nil`, What am i missing.